Why is there no extra memory allocation
When I was conducting the following benchmark test, the benchmark information indicated that there was no additional memory allocation. However, doesn't converting a struct to an interface involve boxing?
        [MemoryDiagnoser]
        public class Test
        {
            [Benchmark]
            public Color Test123()
            {
                Color color = new Color();
                IFormattable formattable = color;
                return (Color)formattable;
            }

            [Benchmark]
            public int Test234()
            {
                int number = 114514;
                IConvertible convertible = number;
                return (int)convertible;
            }
        }
 


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Color : IFormattable
    {
        public double R { get; set; }
        public double G { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }
        public double A { get; set; }

        public static Color GetRandomColor()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            double r = rand.Next(0, 256) * rand.NextDouble();
            double g = rand.Next(0, 256) * rand.NextDouble();
            double b = rand.Next(0, 256) * rand.NextDouble();
            double a = rand.Next(0, 256) * rand.NextDouble();

            return new Color(r, g, b, a);
        }

        public string ToString(string? format, IFormatProvider? formatProvider)
        {
            return $"{R} {G} {B} {A}";
        }

        public Color(double r, double g, double b, double a)
        {
            R = r;
            G = g;
            B = b;
            A = a;
        }
        public static bool operator ==(Color left, Color right)
        {
            return left.R == right.R && left.G == right.G && left.B == right.B && left.A == right.A;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Color left, Color right)
        {
            return !(left == right);
        }
    }

.NET 8
result
The Color struct consists of only four double members: RGBA.
"I tried to open Rider to analyze the IL code and found that there are indeed boxing and unboxing instructions. I would like to understand why there is no additional memory allocation."
  .method public hidebysig static valuetype Program.Color
    Test123() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
      [0] valuetype Program.Color color,
      [1] class [System.Runtime]System.IFormattable formattable,
      [2] valuetype Program.Color V_2
    )

    // [28 9 - 28 10]
    IL_0000: nop

    // [29 13 - 29 39]
    IL_0001: ldloca.s     color
    IL_0003: initobj      Program.Color

    // [30 13 - 30 46]
    IL_0009: ldloc.0      // color
    IL_000a: box          Program.Color
    IL_000f: stloc.1      // formattable

    // [31 13 - 31 39]
    IL_0010: ldloc.1      // formattable
    IL_0011: unbox.any    Program.Color
    IL_0016: stloc.2      // V_2
    IL_0017: br.s         IL_0019

    // [32 9 - 32 10]
    IL_0019: ldloc.2      // V_2
    IL_001a: ret

  } // end of method Program::Test123


This question is similar to: Why does calling an explicit interface implementation on a value type cause it to be boxed?. That question just asks it the other way: "Why does this method create boxing but the other doesn't?" whereas your question is just the second half "Why does this method avoid boxing?"

IIRC, with MemoryDiagnoser, the benchmark only considers allocations in the managed memory (if there's any, you should see a [GEN 0] column - with the value of 1, here). Your code is then subject to optimizations (Devirtualization has been already mentioned). It would also be more evident if you performed the benchmark in Release mode (looking at the generated IL, it appears you're testing in Debug mode)

BenchmarkDotNet does not support benchmarking in Debug mode; benchmarks are conducted in Release mode.

Hmm, I probably worded that incorrectly => the IL you're showing here appears to be generated when building in Debug mode. But you can test in debug mode

I was indeed looking at it in Debug mode, but I just noticed in Rider that even in Release mode, it generates the same IL code as in Debug mode.

That's not possible. Make sure that your Project's configuration has optimizations enabled (<Optimize>true</Optimize>, should be like that by default). Note that I'm not familiar with Raider, but IL is IL

The JIT compiler is smart enough to remove the formattable gymnastics and essentially return just the color
If you change the method to actually return IFormattable, you will have allocations:
public IFormattable Test123() {
    Color color = new Color();
    IFormattable formattable = color;
    return formattable;
}


This optimization is known as Devirtualization, which gained improvements in .NET 6 and in .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.1.

@RaymondChen I am not sure it's devirtualization per se? Isn't that only for making interface/virtual calls

Oops, you're right. I thought there was a virtual call. This is statically deducing the cast, which is a different optimization.
